# upgrade from EF 6.13 to 6.2.0 Migration history breaks

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I upgraded from `Entity Framework 6.1.3` to `6.2.0` then it says there are pending changes, when I run `update-database`, it is trying apply changes from my very first migration and obviously it finds those tables already there in DB and throws error.

Same issue is logged over here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/642

I am on `.NET 4.6.1`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to remove all Entity Framework and dependencies and reinstall it? it can be done from NuGet console `Uninstall-Package FullPackageName –RemoveDependencies`. i have resolved lot of problems with EF and NHibernate this way.

Comment: @MaciejS. that did not help

Comment: have you tried to clean solution and rebuild it all? removing `obj` and `bin` folders from your solution can help as well. remeber to make some backup copy of all project folder somewhere in case of project damage.

Comment: this worked for me "Update-DataBase –script -Force"

Comment: well... i thought that your problem is overall... but glad to hear that something worked correctly. it's valuable information also for me, bacause I also work with EF.